# Redirecting from custom Adminhtml controller

Tags: magento

I am trying to redirect to the admin Order View page from my custom controller. Nothing has worked for me.

I have tried this:

```
$this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => 1));
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("*/sales_order/view", array('order_id'=>'1'));
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view", array('order_id'=> '1')));
```

In that order and nothing has worked.

Could it be that I did not extend from the core controller correctly?
Here's my code:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mycompany_adminhtml after="Mage_Adminhtml">MyCompany_Adminhtml</mycompany_adminhtml>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Controller

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php';

class MyCompany_Adminhtml_PayController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{

public function paidAction()

        {
           $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => 1));
        }
```

I am out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a return clause to the end of your controller action like this:

```
 return $this;
```